# Monogenic function fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, positive-characteristic, function-fields

Recall that a number field $K$ is said to be monogenic if its ring of integers is of the form $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, or equivalently, if it has a power integral basis. There are many references one can consult about the number fields case, this type of fields has been studied in particular in connection to diophantine equations. My interest is in the global function fields analogue, say finite extensions $F/\mathbb{F}_q[T]$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the finite field with $q$ elements. The "ring of integers" in this case is the ring of elements regular away from a fixed place $\infty$. I have been googling around and did not find as many sources (books, papers, ...) on that as I expected. My naive question is: is it not as interesting as the number fields case? If so, what might be the reason?

In the number fields case, Dedekind gave a criterion for monogeneity (or non-monogeneity) of number fields. I am wondering if there is anything analogous for function fields.

Thank you.

Comment: (1) Such monogenic extensions are the same thing as smooth curves in $\mathbb A^2$ whose projection to $\mathbb A^1$ is finite. One possible explanation for why there is less research on these is people might be inclined to study them geometrically more than arithmetically. (2) Sure, Dedekind's criterion works in this setting. The proof is the same.

Comment: @WillSawin. Thank you for your answer. But let me elaborate a bit to see if I understand properly, and perhaps ask another question if you don't mind. Say $F$ is the function field of a smooth and geometrically irreducible curve $\mathcal{C}$ defined by an equation $f(T,y) =0$. My guess is that $\{1, y, \cdots, y^{n-1}\}$ is a power integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_F$, where $n$ is the dimension of $F$ as an $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$-vector space. If what I said is true, where does the part "whose projection to $\mathbb{A}^1$  is finite" fits in this picture?

Comment: Consider dee the curve $yt-1$. For this, you need arbitrarily large powers of $y$. This is an example where projection is not finite.

Comment: I see. I guess those curves are exactly the ones for which the coordinate rings are not finitely generated as $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$-modules, so that you need arbitrarily large powers of $y$ to get a basis. Thanks, that was really helpful.